# Can you define which Java Version your Java web application should use

Tags: java, eclipse

Can you define anywhere in your Java Project which JRE/JDK version should it pick up?

In eclipse when I choose the project >> right click >> Java Compiler and check the "Compiler compliance level" I see a certain version marked (1.7,1.6 etc).  How is this chosen?

Or is this entirely just dependent on what JDK/JRE runtime version your server (tomcat) is using?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:
No, you can not identify the version of java that will be "picked up" at runtime.

More of an Answer:
There are three Java versions that come into play when building and running something using Java.

1. The source version.  This is the version of Java to which the source of the project complies.  When compiling, you can pass a "source" (try google search for "set java source level") parameter to identify this version.  In practice, I don't know the value of this.
2. The target version.  This is the version of Java to which the compiled result will comply.  As with "source version" you can pass this as a parameter to the compiler.
3. Runtime version.  This is the version of java that is actually installed on the host that is running the compiled java (the byte codes).  You can never configure this at compile time since this is the thing that is installed on the runtime host.

There are some caveats.

1. The source and target version numbers must be equal to or less than the version of the java compiler that is actually compiling the java source.  For example, you can choose target version 1.7 if you are compiling using a version 1.8 java compiler.  You may not choose target version 1.8 if you are compiling using version a 1.7 java compiler.
2. It is possible to install multiple versions of java on a host.  It is not possible to choose which version of java tomcat will use to execute your application since the version of java that will be used by tomcat is the version of java that is running tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

It is chosen in that drop down menu, you can set it to whatever you'd like.  However, you must have that version installed on your system/server in order for the project to function correctly. If you go to Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs, you can see which JREs you have installed. When you create a new server element in eclipse, you can also set the JRE of the runtime, and just make sure it matches the version of your project.

Comment: when I deploy my app to a remote server - and that remote server does support Java 1.8,1.7 and 1.6 - where (which config, web.xml, pom?) do I tell that server that my application would only run on Java 1.7? Thanks.

Comment: You don't tell the server that, the server has its own runtime, and the JRE of that runtime must match up.  It will only be running one of 1.8, 1.7, or 1.6, not all three at once.  If your project is 1.7, you will want to ensure that the server runtime JRE is also 1.7